# How to do set partition in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, np

I've just read about possibility to solve set partition to half in polynomial time. But I could not find algorithm to do it.

I have two questions:

1. Where I can get that algorithm?
2. How is it possible that NP problem can be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: Please state the precise problem you wish to solve.

Comment: I would like to know polynomial algorithm to solve set partition, which is NP problem.

Comment: The partition problem is not solvable in polynomial time. It's solvable in pseudo-polynomial time, and there are polynomial-time heuristic algorithms that solve "many instances" of the problem (but not all of them).

Comment: @harold: if this is answer, i would check it like best.

Comment: @harold: So, if I find polynomial algorithm that always can say if there is solution, but do not find all possible instances, would be this algorithm prove of NP=P? Or there is needed to find all instances of problem for prove of NP=P?

Comment: Many NP-complete (merely NP is not really relevant here) problems have "simple instances" that a polynomial algorithm can solve. Consider graph colouring, clearly NP-complete, but Perfect Graphs can be coloured in linear time, and graphs with no edges are pretty much coloured already. The existence of those algorithms does not prove anything about NP?=P.

Answer (score 4):

You should mention *where* exactly did you read that. It's possible that you stumbled upon a polynomial *approximation* algorithm, or a *pseudo-polynomial* exact algorithm (a dynamic programming pseudo-polynomial solution [exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Methods)), but definitely not a polynomial, exact algorithm - since the partition problem is an NP problem, and no polynomial algorithm can solve it, unless P=NP.

Comment: If you could just quickly answer "does P=NP" I'll give you an up vote.

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain

Comment: Seriously. Even though no formal proof exists for P=NP or P!=NP, the general consensus seems to be that P!=NP.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, it's NP-complete and thus far there is no way to solve an NP-complete problem in P time.

Comment: Well... We **think** that there isn't a polynomial time solution.  If P = NP, then there is a polynomial-time algorithm!

Comment: you should write NP-complete instead of NP.

Comment: @templatetypedef - hence "thus far"